# Spaces between controls in Web Form Pages

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I followed the tutorial in this webpage: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4cbh4dh.aspx

In the "Adding and Programming Controls", After step 4 and step 5, why TextBox control and Button control in the illustration has some empty space, but for me, there is not any space since Visual Studio always stops me from dropping the Button control a little far away from TextBox controls. Any solution for me, so I can have some empty space for TextBox control and Button control? Thanks for your time.

P.S. In IT company, which way is more common for developing website, using Design view or Source View?

Updated: Actually my questions: Do you know why Visual Studio always stops me from dropping the Button control a little far away from TextBox controls? Could we fix this problem in Design view, instead of in Source View?

Comment: Why don't you do the research? Everything you need is already out there.

Comment: Which way is more common? Definitely just editing the source. It's faster and results in cleaner code. To be honest I've never seen anybody use the designer seriously

Comment: This more like a `HTML` question, not `C#`. Just add `&nbsp;` between your elements

Comment: Hi Jonathan, what is keywords can I use for searching this question? Do you know why Visual Studio always stops me from dropping the Button control a little far away from TextBox controls? Could we fix this problem in Design view, instead of in Source View?

Comment: Seriously @love1point, nobody uses the designer irl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch to code view and add`&nbsp;` to add space between button and the text box.

Comment: Do you know why Visual Studio always stops me from dropping the Button control a little far away from TextBox controls? Could we fix this problem in Design view, instead of in Source View?

Comment: In design view, you can place cursor between textbox and button and hit space bar. This has the same effect as adding the code i mentioned earlier. The reason visual studio don't let you drop the control, might be the layout you chose for the user control.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the space between two controls in many ways. One straight way is adding the   . But the preferred way is to add css styles to the controls. You can do it by going back to source view and add the below style into the control's html code.

```
style="margin:4px;"
```

To answer your P.S. use source view almost always. You can drag and drop a control in source view also.

Comment: "You can drag and drop a control in source view also." Do you mean cut and paste? I could not drag and drop a control in source view

Comment: It is possible to drag a control from the tool bar into the source view. It will bring the html source code at the place where you drop it. Which version of visual studio are you using?

Comment: I misunderstood your sentences previously. I used VS2015. Yes, it can drag a control from the toolbox to Source view. I thought it can drag a control in the Source view.